# Encoding French characters in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, character-encoding

I have an XML document full of "producers":

```
<producer>
   <name></name>
   <owner></owner>
   <address>
      <civic></civic>
      <mailing/>
      <town></town>
      <province></province>
      <postal></postal>
      <phone></phone>
      <fax></fax>
      <email></email>
      <website/>
   </address>
   <products>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
      <product></product>
   </products>
   <exports>
      <region></region>
      <region></region>
      <region></region>
      <region>l'Amérique du Nord</region>
   </exports>
</producer>
```

For example I want to search for the phrase "l'Amérique du Nord", which is one of the regions for this particular producer:

```
$query = "l'Amérique du Nord";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../business-directory/producers-fr-nb.xml");

$upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜ"; 
$lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàâæçèéêëîïôœùûü"; 

$nodes = $xml->xpath('//producers/producer[descendant::*[contains(translate(text(), "'.$upper.'", "'.$lower.'"), "'.$query.'")]]');
```

It didn't work. I determined the problem to be when I store the phrase "l'Amérique du Nord" in the string $query. When I echo $query I get this: l'AmÃ©rique du Nord

I've used functions like htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() to try encode the é but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: http://pokit.org/get/193d949c1f7beef59a63ccb2d970c3fc.jpg ?

Comment: Funny enough, that was the problem. Somewhere along the line there were two different encodings. I just went through made sure they were all the same (UTF-8) and voila!

Comment: Don't forget, that if your product for instance can contain a `&` or something you should enclose it in a `CDATA` enclosure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look ma, I answered :)

[image]